# How to turn an operation and timestamp in rows into separate columns using PL SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, gaps-and-islands

I tried using sql pivot, but it's not working, getting null value.

Before data:

```
NAME    OPERATION   TIMESTAMP
A       START      18/01/2024 8:24
A       START      18/01/2024 8:27
A       START      18/01/2024 8:30
A       END        18/01/2024 8:34
B       START      18/01/2024 9:28
B       END        18/01/2024 9:32
B       START      18/01/2024 9:37
B       END        18/01/2024 9:39
C       START      18/01/2024 10:14
C       END        18/01/2024 10:18
```

After data (What I need):

```
NAME    START_EVENT START_TIME       END_EVENT  END_TIME         DURATION
A       START       18/01/2024 8:24  END        18/01/2024 8:34  0.006944444
B       START       18/01/2024 9:28  END        18/01/2024 9:32  0.002777778
B       START       18/01/2024 9:37  END        18/01/2024 9:39  0.001388889
C       START       18/01/2024 10:14 END        18/01/2024 10:18 0.002777778
```

Comment: How can you uniquely identify which END belongs to which START? I have the feeling we're missing some information here.

Comment: There are ID before the name which I forgot to include in. So it will be based on the ID (ascending). For example Name B, the END time should not be greater than the next START time for the same name.

Comment: How do you decide that 18/01/2024 8:34 should correspond to 18/01/2024 8:24 and not  18/01/2024 8:27 or 18/01/2024 8:30?

Comment: Only need to get the min START time (ignore any START in between) and the max END time in the same name.

Answer (score 0):

From Oracle 12, you can use `MATCH_RECOGNIZE` for row-by-row pattern matching:

```sql
SELECT name,
       start_event,
       start_time,
       end_event,
       end_time,
       end_time - start_time AS duration
FROM   table_name
       MATCH_RECOGNIZE(
         PARTITION BY name
         ORDER BY timestamp
         MEASURES
           FIRST(operation) AS start_event,
           FIRST(timestamp) AS start_time,
           LAST(operation)  AS end_event,
           LAST(timestamp)  AS end_time
         PATTERN (start_op+ end_op)
         DEFINE
           start_op AS operation = 'START',
           end_op   AS operation = 'END'
       )
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (NAME, OPERATION, TIMESTAMP) AS
SELECT 'A', 'START', DATE '2024-01-18' + INTERVAL '08:24:00' HOUR TO SECOND FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'A', 'START', DATE '2024-01-18' + INTERVAL '08:27:00' HOUR TO SECOND FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'A', 'START', DATE '2024-01-18' + INTERVAL '08:30:00' HOUR TO SECOND FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'A', 'END',   DATE '2024-01-18' + INTERVAL '08:34:00' HOUR TO SECOND FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'B', 'START', DATE '2024-01-18' + INTERVAL '09:28:00' HOUR TO SECOND FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'B', 'END',   DATE '2024-01-18' + INTERVAL '09:32:00' HOUR TO SECOND FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'B', 'START', DATE '2024-01-18' + INTERVAL '09:37:00' HOUR TO SECOND FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'B', 'END',   DATE '2024-01-18' + INTERVAL '09:39:00' HOUR TO SECOND FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'C', 'START', DATE '2024-01-18' + INTERVAL '10:14:00' HOUR TO SECOND FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'C', 'END',   DATE '2024-01-18' + INTERVAL '10:18:00' HOUR TO SECOND FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

| NAME | START_EVENT | START_TIME | END_EVENT | END_TIME | DURATION |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | START | 2024-01-18 08:24:00 | END | 2024-01-18 08:34:00 | .006944444444444444444444444444444444444444 |
| B | START | 2024-01-18 09:28:00 | END | 2024-01-18 09:32:00 | .002777777777777777777777777777777777777778 |
| B | START | 2024-01-18 09:37:00 | END | 2024-01-18 09:39:00 | .001388888888888888888888888888888888888889 |
| C | START | 2024-01-18 10:14:00 | END | 2024-01-18 10:18:00 | .002777777777777777777777777777777777777778 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/pYwg9JJV)

Answer (score 0):

You're facing an issue known as the *gaps and islands* problem. To address it, we'll assign a unique ID to each consecutive group of rows, indicating their start and end. This can be achieved by leveraging the difference between the row number and the cumulative total :

```
WITH cte AS (
  SELECT name, operation, timestamp,
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY name ORDER BY timestamp DESC) 
       - SUM(CASE WHEN operation = 'START' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) OVER (PARTITION BY name ORDER BY timestamp DESC) as grp
  FROM mytable
)
SELECT name, 
       MIN(CASE WHEN OPERATION = 'START' THEN 'START' END) AS START_EVENT,
       MIN(CASE WHEN OPERATION = 'START' THEN TIMESTAMP END) AS START_TIME,
       MIN(CASE WHEN OPERATION = 'END' THEN 'END' END) AS END_EVENT,
       MIN(CASE WHEN OPERATION = 'END' THEN TIMESTAMP END) AS END_TIME,
       MIN(CASE WHEN OPERATION = 'END' THEN TIMESTAMP END) 
       - MIN(CASE WHEN OPERATION = 'START' THEN TIMESTAMP END) AS duration
FROM cte
GROUP BY name, grp
ORDER BY name, START_EVENT
```

Results :

| NAME | START_EVENT | START_TIME | END_EVENT | END_TIME | DURATION |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | START | 18/01/2024 08:24:00 | END | 18/01/2024 08:34:00 | +000000000 00:10:00.000000 |
| B | START | 18/01/2024 09:28:00 | END | 18/01/2024 09:32:00 | +000000000 00:04:00.000000 |
| B | START | 18/01/2024 09:37:00 | END | 18/01/2024 09:39:00 | +000000000 00:02:00.000000 |
| C | START | 18/01/2024 10:14:00 | END | 18/01/2024 10:18:00 | +000000000 00:04:00.000000 |

[Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/qAB_jEpG)